# Javascript: How to attribute the value of the each item in dataframe

Tags: javascript, dataframe

I would like to assign grades for each subject, the objective is to retrieve a subject and its corresponding grade in dataframe

| subject | grades |
| --- | --- |
| maths | 15 |
| French | 12 |
| English | 10 |
| Science | 08 |

I will obtain that:

```json
{
  "values": {
    "maths": 15,
    "French": 12,
    "English": 10,
    "Science": 08
  }
}
```

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){    
    trans = data["subject"][i];        
    res = data["grades"][i];    
return cor = {'values':{             
                  res : trans   }}  
return cor
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? How to access a value in an object? Like `values.English` or `values['English']` will work.

Comment: I will access a value in an object : Like "values.English"

Comment: No I mean what is the problem then?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
 trans = data["subject"][i];
       res = data["grades"][i];
 return cor = {'values':{
       res : trans
 }}
 return cor`

Comment: I don't obtain with this code

Comment: Post it in your question so people can help you

Comment: It seems like you want to retrieve the data from a `<table>` element, and from that create an object to match the subject to the score?

Comment: Yes, want to retrieve the data from a <table> element, and from that create an object to match the subject to the score

Comment: So can you post your "*[mcve]*" HTML and JavaScript (use the [edit] link below the tags to your question)?